# double pointer segmentation fault

Tags: c++

```
class abc ;
void getdata(abc **input=NULL);

class abc {
    int x ;

    public :
    void setX(int in) { x = in ; }
    int  getX()  { return x ; }
};

void getdata(abc **input){
    abc *ap = new abc;
    cout<< "ap ="<<ap <<endl;
    ap->setX(10);
    input = new abc*;
    *input = ap ;
}

int main() {
    abc *a1 ;
    cout << a1 <<endl ;
    getdata(&a1);
    cout<< a1 <<endl;

    cout<< a1->getX()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving segmentation fault , means a1 is coming null .
If i remove  **input = new abc***; it works fine .
I do not understand the logic .

Answer (score 3):

In the line

```
getdata(&a1);
```

You are sending the address of a1 to `getdata`
It need that address, to access `a1`

Then in

```
input = new abc*;
```

You overwrite that pointer. The function `getdata` no longer "remember" the address of `a1`

then in

```
*input = ap
```

you are writing to that new (useless) address.
When the program gets to

```
a1->getX()
```

`a1` was never written to, and is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

By including the line `input = new abc*;` you are changing the value of `input`, and not what `input` points to, which remains undefined unless you remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

At first `input` pointed to `a1`. But when you did `input = new abc*;`, it stopped pointing to `a1`. So remove the line.

```
void getdata(abc **input) // here input points to a1
{
    abc *ap = new abc;
    cout<< "ap ="<<ap <<endl;
    ap->setX(10);

    *input = ap ; // input still points to a1, but value of a1 is changed
                  // you may think this as a1=ap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@user657267 is right, but let me elaborate a little more.

abc, which is declared as `abc *a1 ;`in main, is a variable like any other (say, like an int). It defines a  memory location, likely 4 bytes, which happen to reside on the stack of the function main. That memory is suitable for some data which in this case happens to be an address.

Like with any variable, the memory location where the variable *stores* its data has an address too. This may be confusing at first glance but there is nothing magic about it -- addresses are values too, like any other, and can be stored in variables which occupy some memory somewhere which has its own address.

It is correct to pass the address of a1 to a function which is to change the data held by the variable. Correctly, you apply the operator& to the variable name when you pass its address to the function: `getdata(&a1);`.

getdata() now knows where a1 holds its data, namely at the address which is copied to the formal parameter "input". When getdata wants to change that data, it needs to write to that location. This is done using the operator*, the dereferencing operator.

Now the data in a1 happens to be a (currently probably invalid) address of an abc object. Suitable data to assign to a1 would be an address of an abc object. For example, the pointer ap to the new abc object which was created with `abc *ap = new abc;` is a very good value for such an assignment. And we can access a1 in getdata because we happen to have its address in input. Like with any assignment through an address, we need to use the dereferencing operator* to access the *location* which the address in "input" is describing. (That location is, as we know, the location where a1's data is residing).

**Now what does `input = new abc*;` do?** The right side, "new abc*", creates a location on the heap which can hold an address, likely 4 bytes. Its type is "abc *".

The operator "new" returns the address of the newly created object (that is, the address of the 4 bytes which can hold an address to an abc), and assigns this address to input. **Oy vey -- we have lost the information where main's a1 stores its data!** That was the value "input"  was holding until now. "input" now points to a different, perfectly valid memory location which can hold an address of an abc. `*input = ap ;` writes the address of the abc created at the beginning of getdata() to that memory location. Bummer, the data main's a1 is holding is not changed at all. Because nothing was ever assigned to it the random bytes it contains most likely continue to be a totally invalid address.

So while `*input = ap ;` is perfectly fine, it changes data at the wrong location. Omit overwriting the perfectly valid location of a1's data which input was holding and everything will work. a1's contents will be changed by getdata() which will write the address of a newly created abc object to it, so that dereferencing the pointer, e.g. by `a1->getX()`, will be a valid operation.

In order to avoid accidental overwriting of read-only parameters one can declare them const. In this case `getdata(abc **const input)` would indicate that you do not want to change the value "input" contains. (But you could still *use* that value to access a1's data!) Consequently the assignment `input = new abc*;` would raise a compile time error.